# Is there an alternative way to exit active hacks?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

So far while playing the game I've run into the same issue a number of times where I want to exit out of a hack such as controlling a forklift or camera while there is ongoing dialogue/news playing in relation to the story/mission.

It just so happens that the only known button to exit out of these hacks is ESC but they also close and cancel the dialogue/news reports with no way of bringing them back up essentially accidentally skipping what I personally consider story relevant content.

Is there an alternative button or method to get out of said hacks without also closing the calls and news feeds you receive?

Comment: The game's engine can at least theoretically handle it, since these actions are mapped to different buttons on the PS4 and there's no conflict there. It depends on whether the PC version allows you to (individually) rebind these specific controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finished the game a while ago and I have been unable to find any sort of way to exit hacks without pressing ESC. So the answer to the question I've found is sadly, no there isn't an alternative way.